# Shared Resource Lock

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-safety, asp.net-web-api

I'm using C# on .NET 4.5 - Web API Self Host.
Server-side I've a process that is not thread safe: it can serve one request at a time.
How can I lock this resource (process) in the controller code, so that clients are served sequentially, waiting for the resource to be freed before using it?
Something like:

```
while(true){
    if(!process.isLocked)
        break;
}

lock(process)
do(work)
unlock(process)
warn(others)
```

Any code snippet or suggestion are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for the `lock` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for each thread to execute, but only one at a time, then you can use the `lock` statement with a static object:

```
private static object lockobj = new object();

public void DoWorkWhenNotBusy()
{
    lock (lockobj)
    {
        // do work
        Console.WriteLine("Working #1 (should always complete)...");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

If you want the thread to return immediately if the object is locked, then you can write it like this (double-checked locking):

```
private static object lockobj2 = new object();
private volatile bool locked = false;

public void DoWorkIfNotBusy()
{
    if (!locked)
    {
        lock (lockobj2)
        {
            if (!locked)
            {
                locked = true;
                // do work
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Working #2 (only if not busy)...");
            }
            locked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Test example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var ts = new ThreadStart(DoWorkWhenNotBusy);
    Thread t = new Thread(ts);
    t.Start();

    var ts2 = new ThreadStart(DoWorkIfNotBusy);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(ts2);
    t2.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} started", i);
}
```

Comment: Would be much better to implement Moniter yourself and use TryEnter for the OnlyIfNotBusy instead of the random boolean. Alot of room for error there.

Comment: @caesay double check locking is fairly standard (although I believe your approach is recommended these days), I don't think that the Moniter appropach was available in older versions of .net framework.

Comment: In your first example, with the single check locking is the work always guaranteed to complete, and to complete in order it was attempted?

Comment: @DanHarris no, because another thread might hold the lock indefinitely. In that case the work would not complete until the lock were released.

Comment: Quoting from the Wikipedia [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) article: *"The pattern, when implemented in some language/hardware combinations, can be unsafe. At times, it can be considered an anti-pattern."*

Answer (score 3):

I would like to expand on dbaseman's answer here. Specifically, his `DoWorkIfNotBusy` method.

I think that is a bad example (due to possible race conditions), and would like to show the way I think the correct way would be:

```
private static readonly object lockobj = new object();

public bool DoWorkIfNotBusy()
{
    bool lockWasTaken = false;
    var temp = lockobj;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);

        if (lockWasTaken) // This crucial test was missing! (Added 2021-04-08)
        {
            //Do work here.. 
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp);
    }
    return lockWasTaken;
}
```

---

Updated 2021-04-08: Added the test to see if the current thread succeeded in acquiring the lock. If not, the code in the critical section should not be executed.

---

Updated 2021-04-09: Below code that shows the need for checking `lockWasTaken`, as a unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public class DummyTests
{
    private static readonly object LockObj = new object();

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMonitor()
    {
        Thread trd1 = StartThread();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Thread trd2 = StartThread();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Thread trd3 = StartThread();

        while (trd1.IsAlive || trd2.IsAlive || trd3.IsAlive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private Thread StartThread()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(parameter => this.ThreadTask());
        thread.Start(nameof(thread));
        Trace.WriteLine($"Started thread {thread.ManagedThreadId}.");
        return thread;
    }

    private void ThreadTask()
    {
        bool lockAcquired = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(LockObj, ref lockAcquired);
            if (lockAcquired)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Lock acquired by thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Lock denied to thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockAcquired)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(LockObj);
                Trace.WriteLine($"Lock released by thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be like this:

```
Started thread 12.
Lock acquired by thread 12.
Started thread 13.
Lock denied to thread 13.
Lock released by thread 12.
Started thread 14.
Lock acquired by thread 14.
Lock released by thread 14.
```

Comment: I'm interested in your {} for preventing a race condition. Can you provide an explanation or documentation on how this happens and how your solution works?

Comment: @R.Schreurs are you sure that there any possibility for the `lockWasTaken` variable to be `false` inside the `try` block? IMHO it should not be possible.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, I am. I try to use this code snippet and that was exactly what I experiencing (on >net 5.0). Without the test, I could have two threads running simultaneously in the critical section.
[Monitor.TryEnter Method on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter) also clearly describes this: 
`lockTaken Boolean` 
_The result of the attempt to acquire the lock, passed by reference. The input must be false. The output is true if the lock is acquired; otherwise, the output is false._

Comment: @R.Schreurs I would like to see a minimal example that demonstrates the feasibility of this case. My understanding is that the `ref bool lockTaken` argument can be `false` only in case of an exception. To be clear I am talking about the [`TryEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter#System_Threading_Monitor_TryEnter_System_Object_System_Boolean__) overload that **doesn't** accept a `TimeSpan timeout` argument.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, you're asking me to prove the documentation of Microsoft correct [See docs on overload TryEnter(Object, Boolean)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Monitor_TryEnter_System_Object_System_Boolean__). I am using the overload without a timespan. My assumption is that this overload will return false, when the section has already been locked, without first waiting if the locked is released before the time out. I am using Hangfire to invoke the code, so it is some work to create a minimal example. Maybe later…

Comment: @R.Schreurs I just realized that the `Monitor.TryEnter` method doesn't block the current thread, waiting for the lock to be acquired. It is equivalent to calling the `TryEnter` overload that includes a timeout, passing a zero timeout. So you were right and I was wrong, and your editing intervention is correct. Sorry for wasting a bit of your time...