# Refuse incomming calls until the first one ends

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, locking

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Web Api 2.2 app with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have a web method with a critical code that I don't want to run it if it is running now. This code insert new data into database, and if there are two calls running it, it will insert the same data into database throwing a PK violation exception.

This is the Web Api method sign:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/CodesManager/InsertNewCodes/{aggregationLevel}")]
public HttpResponseMessage InsertNewCodes(
    byte aggregationLevel)
```

Inside this method there is a call to another class method and I have tried to surround it with a `lock` but I'm not sure if I lock it, next calls will wait to release the lock or they will be refused.

How can I lock this critical part and refuse incoming calls until the first one ends?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503912/shared-resource-lock. I think the double-checked locking in the accepted answer might help you out.

Comment: It is not related to the issue, but you want to use ***HttpPost*** to insert new record into database.

Comment: @Daryl I have used the answer you have suggested me. Thanks.